# DNS - restrict updates

Tags: linux, networking, dns

Say I have 3 IP adresses that I want to point to xyz.example.com one at a time at will.

```
IPs:           DNS names:
192.168.10.11  xyz-1.example.com
192.168.10.12  xyz-2.example.com
192.168.10.13  xyz-3.example.com
               xyz.example.com
```

`xyz.example.com` resolves to one of `xyz-{1,2,3}` based on location.

My scenario is, I want to have `xyz.example.com` point to one of 192. addresses always from multiple servers. Right now I update `/etc/hosts` on all the servers.

Can I have my own DNS server where I update the records and have all the servers use my DNS server? 
How do I restrict these updates only to my server? I mean do not publish anything to higher level DNS servers.

Comment: Sure, of course you can run bind or your preferred DNS server, for restricting them, do you mean preventing them from using any other DNS server than yours?  If so you might be able to do it with a firewall rule, if you are just using this internally you needn't involve anything outside your network though

Comment: No i mean i don't want the higher level DNS servers start resolving to my addresses. I am worried about `notify, also-notify, allow-transfer` options.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you'd want to push out network policy that would statically set dns for all endpoints in question.

This would prevent them from auto pointing to another dns